# Color quantization of an image using K-means clustering (using RGB features)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, k-means

Is it possible to clustering for **RGB + spatial features** of images with matlab?

NOTE: I want to use `kmeans` for clustering.

In fact basicly i want to do one thing, i want to get this image

[image]

from this

[image]

Comment: The question is vague. However, if I understand correctly, you mean you want to use RGB values of an image and spatial features for clustering. If so, then yes, you can do that. One way is to concatenate two feature vectors. For RGB, you can take color histogram for example.

Comment: While clustering i want to consider spatial features of image. Is it possible to extract spatial features of image at matlab?

Comment: Spatial features is a vague term. If you divide image into blocks, and then concatenate color histograms of the blocks, then they would be spatial color features. If you take SIFT feature and pack it into a bag-of-words model, those are spatial feature of gradients. You have to decide what to use. Since you are using RGB features, I think SIFT would make sense.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  You can perhaps use a co-occurrence matrix as the main feature and perform `k`-means on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help, I'm new at Computer Vision, because of this sometimes it is hard for me to understand, your directions.  

In fact basicly i want to do one thing, i want to get this image http://i.imgur.com/L44h8jf.jpg from this http://i.imgur.com/86VuM02.jpg. I want to do this with clustering.

Comment: @seleucia You can arrange your entire image matrix into a Nx3 vector and then run kmeans to extract 4 clusters. Now change each pixel's value to its closest centroid. See my answer.

Comment: Why did you change the image. It is not appropriate to change the post once people have answered you. Also you have framed the question incorrectly, you cannot get back the original image from the quantized image.

Comment: Thank you for your concern about the question, i reedit it and corrected. Since it is exactly used at my project, I shouldn't use  "animal" image.  sorry for in appropriate situation

Comment: Btw, Is there a way that get rid of pixel location too much effect on clustering?.
What do you think normalizing or standardizing rgb values, do you think this will help to get better results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for color quantization.

```
[imgQ,map]= rgb2ind(img,4,'nodither'); %change this 4 to the number of desired colors
                                       %in quantized image
imshow(imgQ,map);
```

Result:

[image: Quantized image]

Using `kmeans` :

```
%img is the original image

imgVec=[reshape(img(:,:,1),[],1) reshape(img(:,:,2),[],1) reshape(img(:,:,3),[],1)];
[imgVecQ,imgVecC]=kmeans(double(imgVec),4); %4 colors
imgVecQK=pdist2(imgVec,imgVecC); %choosing the closest centroid to each pixel, 
[~,indMin]=min(imgVecQK,[],2);   %avoiding double for loop

imgVecNewQ=imgVecC(indMin,:);  %quantizing
imgNewQ=img;
imgNewQ(:,:,1)=reshape(imgVecNewQ(:,1),size(img(:,:,1))); %arranging back into image
imgNewQ(:,:,2)=reshape(imgVecNewQ(:,2),size(img(:,:,1)));
imgNewQ(:,:,3)=reshape(imgVecNewQ(:,3),size(img(:,:,1)));

imshow(img)
figure,imshow(imgNewQ,[]);
```

Result of `kmeans` :

[image: Quantized image by <code>kmeans</code>]

If you want to add distance constraint to `kmeans`, the code will be slightly different. Basically, you need to concatenate pixel coordinates of corresponding pixel vales too. But remember, while assigning nearest centroid to each pixel, assign only the color i.e. the first 3 dimensions, not the last 2. That doesn't make sense, obviously. The code is very similar to the previous, please note the changes and understand them.

```
[col,row]=meshgrid(1:size(img,2),1:size(img,1));
imgVec=[reshape(img(:,:,1),[],1) reshape(img(:,:,2),[],1) reshape(img(:,:,3),[],1) row(:)   col(:)];
[imgVecQ,imgVecC]=kmeans(double(imgVec),4); %4 colors
imgVecQK=pdist2(imgVec(:,1:3),imgVecC(:,1:3));

[~,indMin]=min(imgVecQK,[],2);
imgVecNewQ=imgVecC(indMin,1:3);  %quantizing
imgNewQ=img;
imgNewQ(:,:,1)=reshape(imgVecNewQ(:,1),size(img(:,:,1))); %arranging back into image
imgNewQ(:,:,2)=reshape(imgVecNewQ(:,2),size(img(:,:,1)));
imgNewQ(:,:,3)=reshape(imgVecNewQ(:,3),size(img(:,:,1)));

imshow(img)
figure,imshow(imgNewQ,[]);
```

Result of `kmeans` with distance constraint:

[image]

Comment: +1 - Ah yes.  This is completely different than what the OP described in the original post, but I believe that this is what is desired.  Very nice.

Comment: While we are clustering are we considering image pixel location also?,if not, is it possible to add this feature also for clustering matrix

Comment: You can, but then I think that is going to dominate the `kmeans` decision. Try it. Depending on the result, I can give you further advice. Please edit your question and add it there once you have it.

Comment: Just for your knowledge, you are going towards (something called as) `image segmentation`. If you doing this as an assignment/project, then its fine. But I just wanted to make you aware of better approaches for your problem. Maybe based on graph theory (say normalized cuts -> old, but useful). They are complex though.

Comment: Great post! Nice tips. +1