# K means clustering in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, k-means

I found the below code to segment the images using K means clustering,but in the below code,they are using some calculation to find the min,max values.I know the basic concept of K-means algorithm.but I couldn't understand this code.Can any one please explain.

```
  function [Centroid,new_cluster]=kmeans_algorithm(input_image,k)
% k = 4;
input_image=double(input_image);
new_image=input_image;
input_image=input_image(:);
min_val=min(input_image);
input_image=round(input_image-min_val+1);
length_input_image=length(input_image);
max_val=max(input_image)+1;
hist_gram=zeros(1,max_val);
hist_gram_count=zeros(1,max_val);
for i=1:length_input_image
    if(input_image(i)>0)
        hist_gram(input_image(i))=hist_gram(input_image(i))+1;
    end;
end
IDX=find(hist_gram);
hist_length=length(IDX);
Centroid=(1:k)*max_val/(k+1);
while(true)
    old_Centroid=Centroid;
    for i=1:hist_length
        new_val=abs(IDX(i)-Centroid);
        hist_val=find(new_val==min(new_val));
        hist_gram_count(IDX(i))=hist_val(1);
    end
    for i=1:k,
        loop_count=find(hist_gram_count==i);
        Centroid(i)=sum(loop_count.*hist_gram(loop_count))/sum(hist_gram(loop_count));
    end
    if(Centroid==old_Centroid) break;end;
end
length_input_image=size(new_image);
new_cluster=zeros(length_input_image);
for i=1:length_input_image(1),
    for j=1:length_input_image(2),
        new_val=abs(new_image(i,j)-Centroid);
        loop_count=find(new_val==min(new_val));
        new_cluster(i,j)=loop_count(1);
    end
end
Centroid=Centroid+min_val-1;
```

especially what's the purpose of this `input_image(:)`in the above code. In google they said it like matrix.but still I'm confused,whether this is matrix or array

Comment: You can also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726257/color-quantization-of-an-image-using-k-means-clustering-using-rgb-features/26726929#26726929).

Answer (score 0):

The notation `(:)` collapses a multi-dimensional vector into a column vector.

```
data = rand(10,4);

size(data(:))
%   40  1
```

Then you can apply a normal function to an *entire* multi-dimensional array

```
min(data(:));
```

Instead of to each dimension independently

```
min(min(data));
```

In the code that you have posted, they collapse `input_image` to a column vector just to make it easier to apply functions like `min`, `max`, and `length`.

**Update**

The code that you have posted doesn't actually perform k-means clustering. It simply creates a histogram of all values in the image. They use `min` and `max` to determine the number of bins to use for the histogram.

Comment: Thank you,can you explain why did they use min max length function,in K means algorithm,we need to find the centroid .but here what are they doing?please explain this code.

Comment: @temp Updated. The code doesn't actually perform kmeans clustering (see how `k` is never used)

Comment: Sorry,thats my mistake.I updated it.please go through it

Comment: @temp Knowing what I've told you about `(:)` step through the code yourself. That is really too much to go through and you really only asked a specific question about what `(:)` means and that has been answered.

Comment: Can you please tell me why they are creating histogram with the image values here?

Comment: @temp They use the histogram to determine the number of pixels with each value. This is used to determine the ideal position of the centroids iteratively. As I said, step through the code and read up on kmeans. That's outside the scope of this question